# C Short to Int Conversion

Tags: c, type-conversion

I was given some code that looks like:

```
unsigned int x = 0xDEADBEEF;
unsigned short y = 0xFFFF;
if (x > (signed short) y)
    printf("Hello");
```

However, it's not true that `x > y` when `y` is casted to a signed short (and then implicitly converted to unsigned int in the comparison), it takes on the value of MAX_UINT. Why does this happen? Is `y` getting sign extended, or what else would cause such strange behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unsigned to signed conversion for values that don't fit in the positive values of the signed type is implementation defined. Here, for your particular compiler, probably it turns out to be `-1` and that then converted to unsigned is `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: `...is implementation defined` - hu? Doesn't 6.3.1.8 (Usual arithmetic conversions) of the C standard specify what happens when there are different signs and values that don't fit?

Comment: @Mike No, 6.3.1.8 is meant to find a "common real type" when the operands of a binary operation have different kinds. Here, the relevant paragraph is 6.3.1.3§3.